# Determine if an integer is divisible by 3

Tags: restricted-source, atomic-code-golf

Your goal is to determine if a number is divisible by 3 without using conditionals. 
The input will be an unsigned 8 bit number from 0 to 255. Creativity encouraged!

You are ONLY allowed to use

- Equality/Inequality (`==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`)
- Arithmetic (`+`, `-`, `x`)
- Logical Operators (`!` not, `&&` and, `||`  or)
- Bitwise Operators (`~` not, `&` and, `|` or, `^` xor, `<<`, `>>`, `>>>` arithmetic and logical left and right shifts)
- Constants (it would be better if you kept these small)
- Variable assignment

Output `0` if false, `1` if true.

Standard atomic code-golf rules apply. If you have any questions please leave them in the comments. Example methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844867/check-if-a-number-is-divisible-by-3). A token is any of the above excluding constants and variables.

Comment: @GregHewgill My typo, it should be 8 bit number.

Comment: Are we only allowed to use the above operators? Otherwise, modulo would make this way too easy.

Comment: Also, how about table lookup?

Comment: @Jwosty you are only allowed to use those, but I will take suggestions.

Comment: @GregHewgill If you use a table lookup, you have to count all tokens.

Comment: Is 0 considered to be divisible by 3?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by no conditionals? Is it limited to IF statements, or does it apply to things like loops as well?

Comment: @Ruslan You are only allowed to use the above.

Comment: Can I return `true`/`false` instead of `1`/`0`?

Comment: what about Ruby's to_s or to_i? That is, toString or toInteger

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## C - 2 tokens

```
int div3(int x) {
    return x * 0xAAAAAAAB <= x;
}
```

Seems to work up to 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

Credits to `zalgo("nhahtdh")` for the multiplicative inverse idea.

Comment: +1. Was baffled a bit at how the `<=` works, and remembered that 0xAAAAAAAB is taken to be `unsigned int` type, thus the result of multiplication is unsigned.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma inequality operators are allowed, not banned

Comment: @aditsu Oops! I need to read more carefully sometimes! +1 great answer!

Comment: @aditsu, sorry I'm noob, how exactly does this work?

Comment: @Kartik_Koro 0xAAAAAAAB * 3 == 1 due to overflow, so for any int x, x * 0xAAAAAAAB * 3 == x. Also y * 3 has different values for different y, therefore y = x * 0xAAAAAAAB must be the only y such that y * 3 == x. If x is a multiple of 3, then y must be x/3, otherwise it must be working through overflow. A simple way to check is to compare y with x. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: @aditsu I see, +1'd thats great :D

Comment: The challenge states that the input should be unsigned. Maybe `uint8_t x` instead of `int`?

Comment: @200_success The code is compatible with the specified type and range, I see no reason to restrict it.

Answer (score 17):

## Python, <strike>3</strike> 2 tokens

Brute force solution, but it works.

```python
0x9249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249>>x&1
```

Thanks to Howard for the 1 token reduction.

Comment: Wow! Your solution is probably the shortest (3 tokens), but I want to encourage other answers too.

Comment: There is even a 2 token solution: `0x9......>>x&1`.

Answer (score 7):

### C - <s>5</s> 4 (?) tokens

```
int div3_m2(uint32_t n) {
    return n == 3 * (n * 0xAAAAAAABull >> 33);
}
```

Works for **any unsigned 32-bit number**.

This code makes use of multiplicative inverse modulo 2<sup>32</sup> of a divisor to convert division operation into multiplication operation.

**Edit**

My solution (posted 2 minutes after) has the same spirit as aditsu's solution. Credit to him for the use of `==` that improves my solution by 1 token.

#### Reference

- [Labor of Division - ridiculousfish.com](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/labor-of-division-episode-i.html)
- [Hacker's Delight - Magic Number](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm)
- [Wikipedia - Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)

Comment: This is incredible. I knew about magic numbers from the famous inverse squareroot trick, but I didn't know it could be used for an arbitrary divisor. This is `Bull` :P

Comment: Yep, 0xAAAAAAAB = (2^33 + 1)/3 and 171 = (2^9 + 1)/3. I picked the smallest constant that does the trick. Hmm, actually it also seems to work with 86 = (2^8 + 2)/3

Comment: Rats, even 43 = (2^7 + 1)/3 works, not sure how I missed it. Edited now.

Answer (score 4):

## C - 15 (?) tokens

```
int div3_m1(unsigned int n) {
    n = (n & 0xf) + (n >> 4);
    n = (n & 0x3) + (n >> 2);
    n = (n & 0x3) + (n >> 2);
    return n == 0 || n == 3;
}
```

Since 4 ≡ 1 (mod 3), we have 4<sup>n</sup> ≡ 1 (mod 3). The digit summing rule is not limited to summing the digits, but also allows us to arbitrarily break the number into sequences of digits and sum all of them up while maintaining the congruency.

An example in base 10, divisor = 9:

1234 ≡ 12 + 34 ≡ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ≡ 123 + 4 ≡ 1 (mod 9)

All statements in the program makes use of this property. It can actually be simplified to a loop that runs the statement `n = (n & 0x3) + (n >> 2);` until `n < 4`, since the statement simply breaks the number in base-4 at the least significant digit and add the 2 parts up.

Comment: +1: interestingly this works for n up to 512 (actually n = 590), but I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: @PaulR: It won't work for bigger numbers due to carry (note that I used addition in the calculation). Also note the repeated lines.

Comment: Yes, I'm just not sure why it works for 9 bit values, since it only seems to be testing 8 bits?

Comment: for 9-bit numbers after the first addition it become at most 5 bits, after the first `n = (n & 0x3) + (n >> 2);` the result is reduced to 3 bits and the repetition caused it to remain only 2 bits http://stackoverflow.com/a/3421654/995714

Comment: oh I've made a mistake. A 5-bit number + a 4-bit number can result in a 6-bit number. But if n <= 588 adding the top 4 bits and bottom 2 bits of that 6-bit number produce an only 4-bit sum. Again adding that results in a 2-bit number. 589 and 590 results in 3 bits in the last sum but incidentally they aren't divisible by 3 so the result is correct

Answer (score 2):

## Python (2 tokens?)

```
1&66166908135609254527754848576393090201868562666080322308261476575950359794249L>>x
```

Or

```
1&0x9249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249249L>>x
```

Or

```
1&0b1001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001001>>x
```

Comment: Duplicate of Howard's comment

Comment: @aditsu ... Great minds think alike? I swear I didn't see that before I posted this.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript - 3 tokens

```
function div3(n) {
    var a = n * 0.3333333333333333;
    return (a | 0) == a;
}
```

This abuses the fact that using bitwise operators on a number truncates it to an integer in JavaScript.

Comment: Should be 4 tokens: `=`, `*`, `|`, `==`

Comment: I don't think variable assignment counts as a token.

Answer (score 1):

## C - 4 tokens

```
int div3(int x) {
    return ((x * 43) >> 7) * 3 == x;
}
```

Works up to 383.

Previous version (bigger constants):

```
int div3(int x) {
    return ((x * 171) >> 9) * 3 == x;
}
```

Works up to 1535

Answer (score 1):

## **Befunge 93 - 5 tokens**

**Fixed - division removed.**

```
v      @._1.@
         \   
         0   
         +   
         3   
>&>3-:0\`|   
  ^      <
```

Gets input, keeps subtracting 3 until it's smaller than 0, direct the pointer up ('|'), then adds 3. If the value is 0 then the pointer moves right ("*1.@" outputs '1') else moves left ("@.*" outputs '0'). '@' terminates the program.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 6(?) tokens

I'm really not sure how to count tokens.  OP, can you score me?

I think it's 6... `1`, `0`, `0`, `*`, `255`, `x`

Note that the `*` is not integer multiplication.

```ruby
def div3(x)
  ([1,0,0]*255)[x]
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't a token in the OP's sense be only one of the above listed in the question?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 So what? 0?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 maybe 4 for constants?

Comment: @NotthatCharles No, one. `A token is any of the above excluding constants and variables.` So constants are “non-tokens” (for the purposes of scoring), but the asterisk is a token still.

Answer (score 0):

## Python - 25 tokens

To get things started, I have a lengthy solution that is a implementation of one of the answers in the link in my first post. `n` is input.

```
a = (n>>7)-((n&64)>>6)+((n&32)>>5)-((n&16)>>4)+((n&8)>>3)-((n&4)>>2)+((n&2)>>1)-(n&1)
print(a==0 or a==3)
```

`or` is equivalent to `||`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 83 bytes

```
proc T n {while \$n>9 {set n [expr [join [split $n ""] +]]};expr {$n in {0 3 6 9}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsIwFET3nmIo2YmgFQvV4im6S7MKAb@ENCQRC59/9hh1NcN7zBTra41ptZgRwO8HeYdFhfsIzq40pt0WE/RzpdZz9FSgArrOYG@M3H6WG2majzhjwCgi9TsmHE67/yVrCjaBzNRfBgHHV8lQdF2g55ZG6gc)

Comment: Failed outgolf: **96 bytes** `proc T n {set n [expr [join [split [expr [join [split $n ""] +]] ""] +]];expr {$n in {0 3 6 9}}}` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzLCsIwFET3fsVQuhPBBxZ8fEZ36V2FgFdCGpIUhcv99jQK7lydYeYwxfpaY5otRgRIdqXBuHdMMM@ZW87Rc/lX9QFdR9gS/Xj7StKGZskeJwy4qGr93DJ2h83rwd5BDAebwHQ/ngeFxKVk9HydYMZG0roC)

Comment: Another fail:**87 bytes** `proc T n {expr {[expr [join [split [expr [join [split $n ""] +]] ""] +]] in {0 3 6 9}}}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcyxCoMwFIXh3ac4iFsRrKVCxcdwS@8UAr0lxJBEWgj32WNw6NTpg//ASdqW4sOmscIhm68PyOpEvTd2UNFbTviTOoe2JVyIftYxD7hhwkNESjQJjP7afF5sTf1lpwOYlvE@CbLfU0TH8xNqrZKUAw)

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 1 token

Pascal does not have bitwise operators.
(Some *dialects* do and some *implementations* use under the hood bitwise operators for operations on the `set` data type nevertheless.)
Since the `in` set membership operator is not listed among the allowed operators, another relational operator is used:

```pascal
    type
        wholeNumberLessThan256 = 0..255;
    
    function divisibleByThree(n: wholeNumberLessThan256): Boolean;
        const
            wholeNumbersLessThan256divisibleByThree = [
                      0,   3,   6,   9,  12,  15,  18,  21,  24,  27,
                     30,  33,  36,  39,  42,  45,  48,  51,  54,  57,
                     60,  63,  66,  69,  72,  75,  78,  81,  84,  87,
                     90,  93,  96,  99, 102, 105, 108, 111, 114, 117,
                    120, 123, 126, 129, 132, 135, 138, 141, 144, 147,
                    150, 153, 156, 159, 162, 165, 168, 171, 174, 177,
                    180, 183, 186, 189, 192, 195, 198, 201, 204, 207,
                    210, 213, 216, 219, 222, 225, 228, 231, 234, 237,
                    240, 243, 246, 249, 252, 255];
        begin
            { In Pascal `<=` denotes the `⊆` operator with sets. }
            divisibleByThree := [n] <= wholeNumbersLessThan256divisibleByThree;
        end;
```

### Extended Pascal, 0 token

NB:
A lookup table could be written in Standard Pascal (ISO standard 7185), too.

```pascal
    type
        wholeNumberLessThan256 = 0‥255;
    
    { The reserved word `protected` is defined by Extended Pascal.
      It just means the value of `n` may not be altered in the definition. }
    function divisibleByThree(protected n: wholeNumberLessThan256): Boolean;
        type
            tableFormat = array[type of n] of Boolean;
        const
            lookupTable = tableFormat[
                      0,   3,   6,   9,  12,  15,  18,  21,  24,  27,
                     30,  33,  36,  39,  42,  45,  48,  51,  54,  57,
                     60,  63,  66,  69,  72,  75,  78,  81,  84,  87,
                     90,  93,  96,  99, 102, 105, 108, 111, 114, 117,
                    120, 123, 126, 129, 132, 135, 138, 141, 144, 147,
                    150, 153, 156, 159, 162, 165, 168, 171, 174, 177,
                    180, 183, 186, 189, 192, 195, 198, 201, 204, 207,
                    210, 213, 216, 219, 222, 225, 228, 231, 234, 237,
                    240, 243, 246, 249, 252, 255: true;
                    otherwise false
                ];
        begin
            divisibleByThree ≔ lookupTable[n];
        end;
```